# "Catchall" Properties in C#?

Tags: c#, php, dynamic

Is it possible to create a "catchall" getter property in C#?

```
class xyzFactory {

   public static object this.*(string name){
       get { return new name();}
  }
}
```

In PHP you would write something like

```
//static getters are new to 5.3, so I didn't put it here.

class xyzFactory{
    public _get($name){ return $name();}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a hack like

```
xyzFactory.Instance.Name
```

where static Instance property is of type `dynamic`

And make you xyzFactory derived from DynamicObject class.

```
public xyzFactory : DynamicObject
{
    private static xyzFactory _instance = new xyzFactory();

    private xyzFactory() { }

    public static dynamic Instance
    {
        get{ return _instance; }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Not in C# 3. In C# 4.0 you could achieve something like this with expando properties and the `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that in C#.  C# is a compiled language and statically resolves method slots at compile time. It doesn't support passing the property name as string or things like that.

Comment: +1 for explanation; I usually deserve downvotes for hopeless answers

Comment: Vitaliy: I disagree. C# 4.0 does not support "catchall properties" as demonstrated in the question. You cannot do `xyzFactory.HelloWorld`, even in C# 4.0. What C# 4.0 supports is essentially dynamically resolving method calls by *name* ONLY on things typed `dynamic`. It's not changing nature of the type itself. Just a syntactic sugar to call a method on an interface with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Vitaliy: I would be happy to see the code so that I can call an arbitrarily named static property as the question shows.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't noticed it's about STATIC properties. I'm withdrawing my -1 vote. Anyway you can achieve this with a hack like
xyz.Instance.HelloWorld. But generally you are right - C# by nature does not support dynamic STATIC properties resolving.

Comment: Vitaliy: I'd argue that even for instance methods, `dynamic` does not add the ability to add a property to a concrete CLR class type. You'll have to do something like `dynamic obj = new xyzFactory();` in which you are explicitly casting the object to `dynamic` at **call site**. Again, you won't be able to do `new xyzFactory().SomeRandomProperty`.

Comment: Hmmm, in case of instance property you can achieve this if xyzFactory is derived from DynamicObject class.

Comment: Vitaliy: No, you can't do that solely by inheriting from `DynamicObject`. You always need to cast the variable to `dynamic` at call site.

Comment: Mehrdad: Yes, but static Instance property I'm suggesting is of type dynamic

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is overload index operator ([]). At least until C# 4.0 is out

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [property pattern](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html) to implement this, as others have said C# won't currently help you implement it though

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with [LinFu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx). It uses a dynamic Proxy to allow for `Duck Typing and Late Binding`, `Ruby-style Mixins`